# How to secure AWS RDS master username and password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it safe to use RDS master username and password in production and deploy codes with those info into instances?

Should I be creating new username and password? If so, where should I store my master username and password securely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all never store RDS master username and password in your code.

Option 1: [Use AWS Key Management Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html) which is the AWS Preferred way of storing Credentials.

Option 2: You can also store RDS credentials in web server's environmental variables and refer them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use master user credentials in your applications directly. One can store these credentials in AWS Secrets Manager and encrypted by a KMS key.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).